# Laravel Eloquent one --> many relationship assigning parent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

User model has many friends primary key id

```
<?php

namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
        public function friends()
        {
            return $this->hasMany(Friend::class);
        }
}
```

Friend model; belongs to user. Foreign key user_id.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Friend extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    //Make sure birthday is always in right format  
    public function setBirthdayAttribute($value)
    {
        //Put in mysql format
    $this->attributes['birthday'] = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($value));
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

Error when updating user with following controller code:

```
/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \App\Friend  $friend
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Request $request, Friend $friend)
{
        $friend->fill($request->all());
        //Assign user to logged in user...does NOT work; things it is a column
        $friend->user = \Auth::user();
        $friend->save();
        return redirect(action('FriendsController@index'));
}
```

Error message when saving:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'user' in 'field list' (SQL: update `friends` set `last_name` = Muench!!, `updated_at` = 2018-09-28 13:26:01, `user` = {"id":1,"name":"Chris","email":"me@chrismuench.com","email_verified_at":null,"created_at":"2018-09-27 19:52:03","updated_at":"2018-09-27 19:52:03","braintree_id":null,"paypal_email":null,"card_brand":null,"card_last_four":null,"trial_ends_at":null} where `id` = 8)
```

Is there a reason I cannot assign user with a user object? I know I could set the user_id column but this would be nice if I could pass around objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to assign object and not property in your controller you need to add the following [mutator](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator)

```
public function setUserAttribute($user)
{
   $this->attributes['user_id'] = $user->id;
}
```

to your `Friend` object.

However it could be quite risky, because relationship name is also `user`, so it's better to use other name (for example `friend_user` and then method name `setFriendUserAttribute`) or to use Eloquent `associate` method instead:

```
$friend->user()->associate(\Auth::user());
```

Comment: I didn't change any of my code and was able to use $friend->user()->associate(\Auth::user());. Is there a reason I cannot do $friend->user->associate(\Auth::user()); I guess I don't understand why I cannot use magic attribute and have to use method.

Comment: Yes, when you work on relationships you use `user()`. But when you want to display it, depending of type of relationship you could use `$friend->user()->first()` or `$friend->users()->get()` but in such case you can also use "shortcut" like `$friend->user` or `$friend->users`